# L2 convergence implies this series is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{\psi_t\}\in l_2$ so $\sum_t \psi_t^2 < \infty$. I don't understand why $\sum_t \psi_t \psi_{t+k} < \sum_t \psi_t^2$ and thus $\sum_t \psi_t \psi_{t+k} < \infty$. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Well, Cauchy-Schwarz would give $\langle \psi_\cdot, \psi_{\cdot + k} \rangle \le \lVert \psi_\cdot \rVert \, \lVert \psi_{\cdot + k} \rVert \le \lVert \psi_\cdot \rVert^2$.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz or the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: How does this follow from AM-GM?

Comment: $$\lvert \psi_t\psi_{t+k}\rvert= \sqrt{\psi_k^2\psi^2_{k+t}}  \leq \frac{\psi_k^2+\psi^2_{k+t}}{2}$$

Comment: A comment: $\ell^2 \neq L^2$ unless we're dealing with the counting measure, and $t$ is a really weird and off-putting choice for a discrete parameter. I've always seen $t$ used for continuous parameters.